# (.bss+0x0): multiple definition of Proxies

Tags: c++

I have this code for automating a robot. It uses some proxy classes from Player - an open-source software for programming robots. I compiled the two cpp files using these commands:

```
g++ -c -Wall  navigation.cpp `pkg-config --cflags playerc++` `pkg-config --libs playerc++`
and
g++ -c -Wall  autonavigation.cpp `pkg-config --cflags playerc++` `pkg-config --libs playerc++`
I then linked the object files (which is where the problem arises):
g++ -o autonavigate  navigation.o autonavigation.o `pkg-config --cflags playerc++` `pkg-config --libs playerc++`.
```

The code is here:

```
erratic@erratic-desktop:~/Desktop/autonav$ g++ -o autonavigate navigation.o 
autonavigation.o `pkg-config --cflags playerc++` `pkg-config --libs playerc++`

autonavigation.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `gHostname'

navigation.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `gPort'

navigation.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `gIndex'

navigation.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `gDebug'

navigation.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `gFrequency'

navigation.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `gDataMode'

navigation.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here

autonavigation.o:(.bss+0xc): multiple definition of `gUseLaser'

navigation.o:(.bss+0xc): first defined here

autonavigation.o: In function `parse_args(int, char**)':

autonavigation.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `parse_args(int, char**)'

navigation.o:navigation.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

autonavigation.o: In function `print_usage(int, char**)':

autonavigation.cpp:(.text+0x101): multiple definition of `print_usage(int, char**)'

navigation.o:navigation.cpp:(.text+0x101): first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Source code from comment:

```
//navigation.h
#include <libplayerc++/playerc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "args.h"
#define PI 3.14159

using namespace std;
using namespace PlayerCc;

class navigation
{
public:
    navigation();
    void autoNavigate(PlayerClient &, LaserProxy &, Position2dProxy &, PtzProxy &, IrProxy &, SonarProxy &);

private:
    void wallFollow(LaserProxy &, Position2dProxy &);
    void obstacleAvoid(IrProxy &, SonarProxy &, PlayerClient &, Position2dProxy &);
};
```

Source for `autonavigation.cpp`:

```
#include "navigation.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PlayerClient robot("localhost");
    LaserProxy lp(&robot,0);
    Position2dProxy pp(&robot,0);
    PtzProxy ptp (&robot,0);
    IrProxy ir(&robot,0);
    SonarProxy sp(&robot, gIndex);

    navigation nav;
    nav.autoNavigate(robot, lp, pp, ptp, ir, sp);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing your code we can only guess, but my guess is that you *define* these variables in a header file that you include in both source files.

You should *declare* the variables, and be using `extern` to tell the compiler that the variables are defined somewhere else. Then in *one* source file you define the variables (i.e. the same as the declarations in the header file but without the `extern` keyword).

For example, lets say I have a variable `hostname` that I want to use in multiple source files, then I make an `extern` declaration in a header file that I include in all source files that needs the variable:

```
extern char hostname[32];
```

Then in one source file I define the variable:

```
char hostname[32];
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim, these names its complaining about are not even in my code. The code is here below
//navigation.h

**/
#include <libplayerc++/playerc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "args.h"

#define PI 3.14159

using namespace std;
using namespace PlayerCc;

class navigation
{
    public:
    navigation();
    void autoNavigate(PlayerClient &, LaserProxy &, Position2dProxy &, PtzProxy &, IrProxy &, SonarProxy &);

    private:
    void wallFollow(LaserProxy &, Position2dProxy &);
    void obstacleAvoid(IrProxy &, SonarProxy &, PlayerClient &, Position2dProxy &); 
};

Comment: //main (autonavigation.cpp)

#include "navigation.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 PlayerClient    robot("localhost");

 LaserProxy      lp(&robot,0);

 Position2dProxy pp(&robot,0);

 PtzProxy   ptp (&robot,0);

 IrProxy         ir(&robot,0);

    SonarProxy   sp(&robot, gIndex);


    navigation nav;

    nav.autoNavigate(robot, lp, pp, ptp, ir, sp);

}

Comment: SOLUTION:
I got it to work by moving "args.h" from navigation.h to main (autonavigation.cpp) as it was getting included twice: in navigation.h directly and in autonavigation.cpp indirectly through the inclusion of navigation.h. The proxy classes are defined in main (autonavigation.cpp) and therefore the "args.h" header only needs to be included there.

Comment: @elefante That doesn't seem correct, the include file should only have been included once as there is only one `#include` directive for it. However, it points to that the error might be in that header file. By the way, if you want to make sure about not including a header file multiple time, you should add [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).