# odd linker error occuring when making program: 'multiple definition of `fnames'; src/main.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here'

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, gnu-make

So I am programming a program that grew so much that I decided to create many files for this project (as I have done before). After creating 2 files and putting the appropriate functions in them these are the errors I get when make-ing.

```
/bin/ld: src/util.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): multiple definition of `fnames'; src/main.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
/bin/ld: src/util.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `gBoard'; src/main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/bin/ld: src/possiblemoves.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): multiple definition of `fnames'; src/main.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
/bin/ld: src/possiblemoves.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `gBoard'; src/main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:22: vgcp] Error 1
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
IDIR=/usr/include/SDL2
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=src

LIBS=-lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

_DEPS = main.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o util.o possiblemoves.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

all: vgcp clean


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

vgcp: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o
```

Comment: There's no issue with the `Makefile`, it would be better if you posted the code (at least relevant snippets) instead, so more specific answers can be produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue just by surfing stack overflow for a bit more...
So it looks like I need to use the `extern` keyword for my variables in the header file. I got my solution from here: [(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511044/bss0x0-multiple-definition-of-proxies)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have variables `fnames` and `gBoard` defined in all of `util.c`, `possiblemoves.c` and `main.c` files, just as the linker is trying to suggest.

The definition must remain in only one of the source files, while you can put a declaration for such variable in the other files if you need to access them from there.

Comment: The problem was the header file. gBoard / fnames were both defined in the header file. They just needed the 'extern' keyword

Comment: @VictorOcampo Since the variables were linked in `.data` segment, I guess they also had also initialisers. Did you move the initialisers to one of the .c files?